# How to disable right click in chrome?

Tags: knockout.js, web-applications

I have a web application(build with knockout using chrome). I want to disable right click but I tried many ways but it still do not work. How to do it?

Comment: yes. i use this way. thankz

Answer (score 1):

This code will disable the right click.

Add the following code in **script tag** - **at the end of your HMTL body**

If you want to disable the right click of for an element just change the  `document.querySelector('body');` to  `document.querySelector('#YOUelementIDhere');`

```
 (function () {
      var blockContextMenu, myElement;

      blockContextMenu = function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
      };

      myElement = document.querySelector('body');
      myElement.addEventListener('contextmenu', blockContextMenu);
    })();
```